# RSpec and Factory Girl - Error with datetime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm with the following problem:

Environment: Ruby: 2.3.1 and Rails 5.0.0.1

I'm trying to validate a datetime field with RSpec and Factory Girl.

I got this error:

```
expected: "2016-11-11 13:30:31 UTC"  (From Factory Girl)
     got: "2016-11-11T13:30:31.218Z" (From database)
```

My code:

```
klass_object = FactoryGirl.create(:character)
klass = Character


RSpec.shared_examples 'API GET #index' do |klass|
  before { get :index, params: params, accept: Mime[:json] }


  it "returns a list of #{klass.to_s.underscore.pluralize}" do
    object_array = json(response.body)

    klass_attributes = klass.attribute_names.without("id", "created_at", "updated_at").map(&:to_sym)

    klass_attributes.each do |attribute|
      object_array.each do |object|
        expect(object[attribute].to_s).to eq(klass_object[attribute].to_s)
      end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :character do
    marvel_id { Faker::Number.number(6).to_i }
    name { Faker::Superhero.name }
    description { Faker::Hipster.paragraphs(1) }
    modified { Faker::Date.between(DateTime.now - 1, DateTime.now) }

    factory :invalid_character do
      id ''
      name ''
      marvel_id ''
      modified ''
    end
  end
```

end

How can I correct this problem?

I did that, it works but I think it is not so good. There is a better way to do it?

```
    object_array.each do |object|
      if ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone == klass_object[attribute].class
        expect(object[attribute].to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).to eq(klass_object[attribute].to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
      else
        expect(object[attribute].to_s).to eq(klass_object[attribute].to_s)
      end
    end
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you to change your approach to compare the results. You can use approach, which based on the idea of the golden master.

In according to this approach you take a snapshot of an object, and then compare all future versions of the object to the snapshot.

In your case you can write json fixture first time, check that json is  correct and compare it with result json next time.

For example

***approved.json***

```
[
  {
    "travel_time_seconds": 43200,
    "available_seats_amount": 10,
    "departure_at": "2016-04-08T02:00:00.000+03:00",
    "arrival_at": "2016-04-08T17:00:00.000+03:00",
    "source_point_name": "New York",
    "destination_point_name": "Moscow",
    "tickets_count": 2
  }
]
```

***controller_spec.rb***

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'API GET #index' do |klass|
  before { get :index, params: params, accept: Mime[:json] }

  it "returns a list of #{klass.to_s.underscore.pluralize}" do
    verify(format: :json) { json(response.body).map {|o| o.except('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at' }
  end
  ...
end
```

[approvals gem](https://github.com/kytrinyx/approvals), for example, can help you with that

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but I just came across the solution to this today and couldn't find another answer.  I've been using Faker too, but the Date/Time formats don't seem to work very well with Ruby time math without a lot of finagling.

However, if you use `Time` in your factory, and then convert it `.to_i`, it will get sent to the db in the correct format for comparison in rspec.

Migration:

```
class CreateExperiences < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :experiences do |t|
      t.datetime :start_date
```

Factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  when_it_started = Time.zone.now - rand(3000).days
  factory :experience do
    start_date { when_it_started.to_i }
```

Spec:

```
RSpec.describe "Experiences API", type: :request do
  let!(:valid_attributes) { attributes_for(:experience) }
  describe "POST /v1/experiences" do
    before { post "/v1/experiences", params: valid_attributes }
      it "creates an experience" do
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body).except("id", "created_at", "updated_at")).to eq(valid_attributes.stringify_keys)
      end
```

Then my tests passed.  Hopefully this will help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `to_datetime` instead `to_s`

```
expect(object[attribute].to_datetime).to eq(klass_object[attribute].to_datetime)
```

Comment: In this case, I am looping for each attribute from the Class. So, not all attributes are datetime.